# Hibernate annotation String convert to Decimal

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using Spring + Hibernate to update price of a product from front-end webapp.
In the backend, I have the following codes:

```
@NotNull(message = "Price is required")
@Range(min = 0, message = "Price must be positive.")
private BigDecimal price;
```

When I test my webapp, I entered the price text box without numbers, just decimal dot like `"."`. Server gives me an error message:

```
    "Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.math.BigDecimal' 
for property 'Price'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException"
```

How should I solve this problem? Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to validate your input string before attempting to enter it into the db.  `"."` is not a valid number.  `"0."` or `"0.0"` would be valid numbers.

Comment: Thanks, I should validate the input string in front end or in back end?

Comment: That's going to depend on what you're trying to do;  that said most applications I can think of would be best off validating the user input string on the front end so you can immediately provide the user with feedback for invalid input

Comment: Also for future reference - always look at the root-cause exception (`nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException"`) when trying to debug.  This is almost always the best way to figure out what your root problem is

Comment: Even if you validate the input on the front-end, you should also validate on the back-end to protect yourself from any requests that do not come through your front-end (hacking).